# Trouble writing webscraping results to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write my output to a csv-file. I've tried with both pandas and csv, but I just get an empty csv-file. What am I missing?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
r = requests.get('https://superstats.dk/program?aar=2018%2F2019')
bs=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

table_div=bs.find(id="content")
rows = table_div.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print (cols)

df= pd.DataFrame(cols, columns=['Dag', 'Dato', 'Hold', 'Resultat', 'Tilskuere', 'Dommer'])
df.to_csv('Superliga.csv', index=none, encoding='utf-8')
```

I want the output from print(cols) in a csv-file.

Comment: `df= pd.DataFrame(cols, columns=['Dag', 'Dato', 'Hold', 'Resultat', 'Tilskuere', 'Dommer'])` uses `cols` which is _repeatedly_ overwritten in your `for row in rows:` loop. All you have left is its final incarnation.

Comment: I'm still new to Python, so sorry if I'm asking a dumb question: Is writing to csv from a dataframe the wrong way to go then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you really worked with `csv` library, but using it's [`csvwriter.writerow(row_values)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method you can easily write data to your csv file row by row.

And talking about using `pandas`, the issue in your code lied in this line:

`df= pd.DataFrame(cols, columns=['Dag', 'Dato', 'Hold', 'Resultat', 'Tilskuere', 'Dommer'])`

The main reason being the usage of 'cols' variable. Let's assume that your table data from the page web page has *n* rows to it. Now, your 'cols' variable gets a row related data in an iterative fashion, thus after *nth* iteration it will contain the data of the *nth* row only. And most probably that *nth* row is empty in the page you linked. Therefore your data frame was empty because you initialized your data frame with an empty list. So, it would be better, if you append the data of 'cols' variable to a list after every iteration. This new variable (let it be 'row_data') which now has a collection of lists can then be used to create a `pandas` data frame.

To put those words in code, see below:

1. **Using `csv` library**

   ```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   #import pandas as pd
   import csv
   r = requests.get('https://superstats.dk/program?aar=2018%2F2019')
   bs=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
   #Create a csv.writer object using the csv file you wish to write in
   writer = csv.writer(open('sample.csv','w'))
   #Use writerow method of the object to write your first row/header contents
   writer.writerow(['Dag', 'Dato', 'Hold', 'Resultat', 'Tilskuere', 'Dommer'])

   table_div=bs.find(id="content")
   rows = table_div.find_all('tr')
   for row in rows:
       cols=row.find_all('td')
       cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
       print (cols)
       #Some cols are empty, therefore avoid writing them to the file 
       if len(cols)>0:
         #Append all the incoming data row by row
         writer.writerow(cols)

   #df= pd.DataFrame(cols, columns=['Dag', 'Dato', 'Hold', 'Resultat', 'Tilskuere', 'Dommer'])
   #df.to_csv('Superliga.csv', index=none, encoding='utf-8')
   ```
2. **Using `pandas` library**

   ```
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import pandas as pd
   import csv
   r = requests.get('https://superstats.dk/program?aar=2018%2F2019')
   bs=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

   #Create an empty list, and use it to append data row by row
   row_data = []

   table_div=bs.find(id="content")
   rows = table_div.find_all('tr')
   for row in rows:
     cols=row.find_all('td')
     cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
     #Some cols are empty, therefore avoid adding them to the 'row_data'
     if len(cols)>0:
       row_data.append(cols[0:6])

   #Create a dataframe in one shot using the 'row_data' variable
   df = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=['Dag', 'Dato', 'Hold', 'Resultat', 'Tilskuere', 'Dommer'])    
   print(df)
   df.to_csv('Superliga.csv', index = None, encoding='utf-8')
   ```